# merge audio and video in nodejs without using ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, audio, video

Im trying to merge audio and video both in mp4 and x264 codec but only with node js in server side **without using ffmpeg**.

is there any way to achieve something like this?
I already tried:
https://github.com/gkozlenko/node-video-lib
but its not working.

any ideas ?

tnx

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: funny question, because I have some videos that have separate video and audio and I try merge them to a single file

Comment: Why don't you want to use FFmpeg though?

Comment: Im using a shared host that doesnt have ffmpeg installed, and the project is a common product that its gonna have easy install, so the end point users wont be able to install ffmpeg for their host

Comment: You would rather re-invent years of work to build something relatively slow unoptimized, without the benefit of broad testing, for the convenience of your users not having to take 3 minutes to install an FFmpeg binary?  That's wild.  Please understand... while you can write a video muxer in JavaScript, and there are situations where the tradeoff is useful, I can't imagine why you would want to do this for server-side script.  Get a new shared host.  For a couple bucks a month, you can have a VPS where you can install whatever you want... and you'll need the extra RAM anyway.